# "this app won\'t work unless you update google play services" error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to implement the google play services sign-in to my app.

I added libraries (Google-play-services lib, basegameutils lib).I have added the sign in button. The app is not crashing. Everything that I have done seems to be ok.

I signed the app with the keytool and export it, then install it to my phone. I added the SHA1 code to my test app on developers console. And added My app Id to my app.

But when I tap on the sign in button it say with a pop-up "this app won\'t work unless you update google play services". When tap on the "update" it seems the service is up to date.

Is this a problem with my device? Or else What can I try to solve that?

My device is Samsung Galaxy S3.

**Update**

I added this code :

```
private boolean checkIfMapsIsOk() {
        int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices, this, 1122).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "err"+checkGooglePlayServices, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and the toast result is "err2".  And I looked up for the error numbers from http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html

It says on that site "public static final int SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED"

"The installed version of Google Play services is out of date. The calling activity should pass this error code to getErrorDialog(int, Activity, int) to get a localized error dialog that will resolve the error when shown.

Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)"

So from this I think the reason for error is my device. But my device sees no updates. It is up to date. This is so strange.

Comment: Tell us what version of Android / google play services you have installed. Also, does this happen in the emulator as well?

Comment: version is 5.2.08. on the emulator it says that emulator doens have Google play services. I created the emultor; selecting nexus one, api level 17 and arm to to its cpu/abi @SepehrFarshid

Comment: You'll probably have to downgrade Google Play Services in your app for now. I ran into this issue myself even though the Play Store says I am up to date.

Comment: Google has recently updated the Google play services library but not all devices have gotten the update to the application.

Comment: @michaelcarrano  how can ı downgrade it? when I write a lower version in dependencies (Android studio) it says there is a newer version and I can debug or export my app .

Comment: I mean I can't debug or export it

Comment: You can downgrade your google play services going to settings > apps > google play services > uninstall updates. and about the libraries, you can try to download  the google play services lib project again, and relink it. Check also your sha1 and if necessary, make a new key. sometimes google maps are a headache with android devices.

Comment: @unmultimedio ok thank you I will try what you said and write the result.

Comment: @unmultimedio Tried all. But not workin :/

Comment: Assuming you are using Gradle, just add this to your dependency: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+' and sync with Gradle again.